# How to import sub-routes from other packages

Tags: rest, go, routes, middleware, go-echo

Instead of writing every route under main(), like

```
func main() {
    e := echo.New()
    e.GET("/api", sayHello)
    e.GET("/api/music", getMusic)
    e.GET("/api/user/:id", getDetail)
    e.POST("/api/user", addUser)
    // ...
}
```

How can I import these all sub-routes from a file called `api.go`, and use those in the main function? Similar to

```
import "./API"
func main() {
    e := echo.New()
    e.UseSubroute(API.Routes) // <-- similar to this
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Files are not importable, in Go you can only import packages. And also do not use relative imports. I would suggest you follow the recommendations from here: https://golang.org/doc/code.html

Comment: @mkopriva Here `api.go` is included in the package: `package API`

Comment: I would also suggest you consider renaming your package (https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#package-names). That said, you can declare a function in your `API` package that takes `*echo.Echo` as its argument and does all the route-to-handler registering.

Comment: About package, I moved the source code to `src/`, ran `go mod init`, upload to Github, then I could use a canonical name starting with `github.com/username/myapp/API`. This feels terrible and very unnatural IMO, but this is Go, isn't it lol.

Comment: with `go mod` *it is not* necessary to have your package in `src/`, without `go mod` *it is* necessary that your package is located in `$GOPATH/src`, however *it is not* necessary to upload your package to github. And also, although it is a convention when using GOPATH, *it is not* necessary that your package is located in `$GOPATH/src/github.com/user/repo`, something like `$GOPATH/src/api` and then `import "api"` will work as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Echo object does not have this method. I think you need the code?

API.go:

```
package main

import "github.com/labstack/echo"

func UseSubroute(echo *echo.Echo)  {
    echo.GET("/api", sayHello)
    echo.GET("/api/music", getMusic)
    echo.GET("/api/user/:id", getDetail)
    echo.POST("/api/user", addUser)
}
```

main.go:

```
package main

import "github.com/labstack/echo"

func main() {
    e := echo.New()
    UseSubroute(e)
}
```

These two files need to be placed in the same directory.

Do you need it?

Comment: Thanks. This works for now. There is still a problem though when trying to achieve the same to `/api/user/xxx`. After all, it would be ugly to write `func UseSubroute()` in every sub-route file.

Answer (score 11):

What you can do is use the `echo.Group` and pass it to the `api` package, and initialize the routes handler there.

```golang
package api

import (
    "github.com/labstack/echo"
)

func UseSubroute(group *echo.Group)  {
    group.GET("/", sayHello)
    group.GET("/music", getMusic)
    group.GET("/user/:id", getDetail)
    group.POST("/user", addUser)
}
```

and in the main you can just import your `api` package.

```golang
package main

import (
    "github.com/labstack/echo"
    "your-repo/path-to/api" // your api package
)

func main() {
    e := echo.New()
    apiGroup := e.Group("/api")
    api.UseSubroute(apiGroup)
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Andy 's idea, I come up with a solution, that supports detachable nested routes.

The current folder structure is as follows:

```
.
├── routes
│   ├── index.go
│   └── music.go
└── server.go
```

...where `server.go` is the project main entry, belongs to the `main` package, while `index.go` and `music.go` belong to `routes` package.

The endpoints are

```
"/api"       -> index.go
"/api/music" -> music.go
```

First in `index.go` we define a function for using routes at this level.

```
func UseRoute(group *echo.Group, routes func(group *echo.Group)) {
    routes(group)
}
```

Then,

in `server.go`

```
func main() {
    e := echo.New()
    apiGroup := e.Group("/api")
    routes.ActivateIndex(mainGroup)
}
```

in `index.go`

```
var mainGroup *echo.Group
func ActivateIndex(g *echo.Group) {
    mainGroup = g
    UseRoute(mainGroup, IndexRoutes)

    // sub routes
    musicGroup := mainGroup.Group("/music")
    ActivateMusic(musicGroup)
}
```

and in `music.go`

```
var musicGroup *echo.Group
func ActivateMusic(g *echo.Group) {
    musicGroup = g
    UseRoute(musicGroup, MusicRoutes)
}
```

Note: `IndexRoutes`, `MusicRoutes` etc. are functions that specify endpoints at this level.

e.g.

```
func IndexRoutes(group *echo.Group) {
    group.GET("/", sayHello)
    group.GET("/user/:id", getDetail)
    group.POST("/user", addUser)
}
```

In this way, the routes can be defined in different `.go` files, making the business logic clearer.

For example, to extend the nested level, we can create another `ActivateHiphop` function in `hiphop.go`, also import the new sub-routes at `ActivateMusic` function from `music.go`, so that `"/api/music/hiphop"` can be pointed to `hiphop.go`.

p.s. To add more routes in `/api` level, just create more endpoints in `IndexRoutes` function.